# Angular ng-repeat with polling data provider

Tags: angularjs, watch, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am just reading about Angular now.

Let's say `ng-repeat` binding is in effect, and child records appear as `<li>` elements beneath the `<ul>`.

Now let's say new objects are  `pushed` onto a `watched` array (watched with `watchCollection`) in the model every 60 seconds by a polling data provider (i.e. the existing data in the array don't change).

Will Angular *append* new counterpart `<li>` elements to the `<ul>` or *completely recreate* the `<ul>` when it detects the array has additional elements?

EDIT: @Blackhole has asked, "Why ask...?", so I'll elaborate with a more complicated hypothetical that matches pretty well my actual app, which I'm thinking of rewriting to learn Angular.

Imagine you have to fetch the manifest for an immensely long freight train and display for your users the contents of each freight car.  You don't want the user to wait and wait and wait, and then suddenly see the entire freight train manifest.  Instead, you ask the server for a list of Car Ids and fetch each car's manifest in turn, and in the `success` callback, you pop another CarId off the array, and fetch the next car's manifest, until the array of Car Ids is empty. You expect the UI to add the current car's manifest to the page immediately, as the next car's manifest is being fetched.

Comment: Completely re-create (if my memory serves me right) - there are a few Angular articles out there that deal with this issue with custom directives. You also wouldnt `watch` the array - your data call should happen within the `$scope` and kick off a new `$digest` cycle.

Comment: @tymeJV's memory is good. But why are asking this question? Seems like a XY problem.

Comment: thats a nice question, im gonna make a quick test here, imho I think it adds new elements when you push new items, and completely recreates when you assign a new array

Comment: @Blackhole: I don't know what an `XY problem` is. The scenario is my question is a lot gentler than the actual situation, where I could be fetching additional data every few hundred milliseconds.  If the container is redrawn every time, there would be lots of inefficiency and screen flashing, since the data I'm fetching are paragraphs of text.

Comment: @Fedaykin: looking forward to your results.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) OK for efficiency, but I doubt there will be any screen flashing: the deletion of the `<ul>` content and the recreation of it is done sequentially, the browser won't refresh until the DOM is ready. And by the way, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Blackhole: the application was actually written over 5 years ago in javascript, but not in Angular, of course, and this particular optimization was not premature, and not evil, but the result of experience, and a good one. Please see my updated question for further details.

Comment: Tim, given the problem above it might make more sense to write your own directive and append the HTML once each call comes back. Once the entire manifest is back is it refreshed in the same way (top down calling) - or only refreshed again on the next page load?

Comment: @tymeJV: I'll read up on creating custom directives.  The manifest is fetched piecemeal, one car at a time, and once the manifest of the caboose has been retrieved, and there are no cars remaining to be queried, the app goes quiet, until the user specifies another freight train, so to speak. Then we have to clear the manifest data from the model, removing the existing manifest elements from the UI, and then start the entire process all over again, with a different "train".

Comment: Well, IMO I dont think performance with a simple `ng-repeat` would be an issue (altho that's easy to say when I haven't seen the data or the UI :D ) - writing a custom directive that won't recreate the UI each time will obviously perform better, but may not even be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick test, I can confirm that when pushing new items to a bound array, the former DOM elements are not recreated.

To prove it, I created a simple array and bound it to a ng-repeat, then I created a Jquery method that changes the DOM elements, note that when you push a new element to array (using angular) the elements that were changed using the jquery method:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.pushItems = function(){
    var newItem = {description: 'Item description ' + $scope.items.length};
    $scope.items.push(newItem);
  }

  $scope.newArray = function(){
    var newArray = [{description: 'First item of new array'}]
    $scope.items = newArray;
  }

  $scope.reassign = function(){
    var newArray = angular.copy($scope.items);
    $scope.items = newArray;
  }

});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#domchanger").click(function(){
      $(".mylist li").html('changed');
    });
});
```

Here is the plunkr with that demonstration: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ScX4ZJJdOrlqWGtivar?p=preview